# ion-input not working in ngIf angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Till `*ngIf` it's working fine. After condition becomes true it's not printing or not creating followed DOM.

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let checklists of leadCheckList" >

  <div *ngIf="checklists.checklistType == 'text' ">                              
    <ion-input type="text"  name="inspectionCheckList" required></ion-input>
  </div>

</ion-item>
```

Comment: Print out your variable by adding `Checklist type is "{{checklists.checklistType}}"` before the div.

Comment: checklist type is getting printed and type is String

Comment: is the value `text`?

Comment: i think your code snippet is not enough to  come to a resolution.

Comment: checklists.checklistType value is 'text' .... if condition becoming true but its not printing following ionic 2 textbox..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not being familiar with Ionic, but did some research. Check [**this**](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/confused-about-ion-item-usage/54116/14) one out, where the question was:

> *I tried to use div elements inside the ion-item and they were ignored.*

and answer:

> *With the addition of `item-content` it's now possible to include HTML elements and custom components inside `<ion-item>` (since beta.8)*

So I made a [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/jOLcoEbjrDwW879Ndxo9?p=preview) for you, where it seems to work fine, and the divs are shown properly when adding `item content` in the div, like so:

```
<div item-content *ngIf="checklists.checklistType == 'text' ">                              
  <ion-input type="text"  name="inspectionCheckList" required></ion-input>
</div>
```